# System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'file path' is not a valid path

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, ms-access

I am coding a login and registration form using windows form in visual studio 2019 and MS Access 2002-2003 as my database but i have come up with a problem as the signup button the registration form wont accept recognize the path i have inserted:

`Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\"C: \\Users\\user\\Documents\\MS Access Database\\log.mdb\"`

i have inserted the double backslashes as it errors on only using one and this is the original one:

`Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="C: \Users\user\Documents\MS Access Database\log.mdb"`

the problem was an exception in External Code. Here's full problem that occurs on the .Open();

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: ''C:\Users\user\source\repos\Management System\Management System\bin\Debug\ \Users\user\Documents\MS Access Database\log.mdb' is not a valid path.  Make sure that the path name is spelled correctly and that you are connected to the server on which the file resides.'

This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]
    Management_System.Registration_Form.signupBtn_Click(object, System.EventArgs) in Registration Form.cs
    [External Code]
    Management_System.Program.Main() in Program.cs
```

these are my codes:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;



namespace Management_System
{
    public partial class Registration_Form : Form
    {

        public Registration_Form()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\"C: \\Users\\user\\Documents\\MS Access Database\\log.mdb\"");
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();

        private void signupBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (signupUser.Text == "" && signupPass.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Username and Password are empty", "Registration Failed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

            }
            else if (signupPass.Text == conpassTxt.Text)
            {
                
                conn.Open();

                string register = "INSERT INTO log VALUES ('" + signupUser.Text + "','" + signupPass.Text + "')";
                cmd = new OleDbCommand(register, conn);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
                

                signupUser.Text = "";
                signupPass.Text = "";
                conpassTxt.Text = "";

                MessageBox.Show("Your Account has been Successfully Created", "Registration Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Your Password do not match, Please Re-enter", "Registration Failed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                signupPass.Text = "";
                conpassTxt.Text = "";
                signupPass.Focus();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried to use the files path itself and still wont work i've also tried to create a new database and edit the code with the new data itself. Any form of help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: It seems to be adding two paths together... finger-in-wind question: have you tried removing the space between `C:` and `\\Users...`? It's almost as if it's seeing "C: " as some sort of reference to a default path. Could be nothing, but takes 30 seconds to try...

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you so much! But now the exception is on the `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`. Im just gonna triple check everything at this point

Comment: Hi, I posted an answer. If it is helpful to you, you can click '✔' to mark your repy as an answer. It will also help other to solve the similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please try removing the space between `C:` and `\\Users`, like this:

```
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\MS Access Database\\log.mdb");
```